# Retrieve multiple tables by one Linq-to-Sql query

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

Currently I am populating a model in my MVC application with **three** database queries.

Here how it goes:

```
IndexViewModel model = new IndexViewModel();

model.Links = Repository.GetAll().ToArray();
model.SourceOne = StaffMembersRepository.GetAll().ToArray();
model.SourceTwo = CategoriesRepository.GetAll().ToArray();

return model;
```

#### I wish to make only one query (for better performance) which should return me all the rows of three tables.

I can't go inner joins because this three tables are not (let's say they are not) connected at all.

I have tried to

```
var result = from link in Repository.GetAll()
             from staffMember in StaffMembersRepository.GetAll()
             from category in CategoriesRepository.GetAll()
             select new { link, staffMember, category };
```

But there is a compile error highlighting the "`CategoriesRepository.GetAll()`" piece of code sayin:

> An expression of type 'System.Linq.IQueryable' is not allowed in a subsequent from clause in a query expression with source type 'System.Linq.IQueryable'.  Type inference failed in the call to 'SelectMany'.

Whatever that means.

Comment: It is impossible to retrieve data from three tables in SQL using only one query (ok, except for a union query, but that's a special case).  What makes you think LINQ, which generates SQL in the background, can do this?  And what makes you think a single LINQ statement is going to perform better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it's possible to retrieve completely unrelated tables through LINQ in one shot. Maybe for performance reasons you should consider caching so you won't need to query the database every time.

With plain SQL on MSSQL you could use batch statements.

```
var batchSql = "select * from Repository; select * from StaffMembersRepository; select * from CategoriesRepository";
// ...
// iterate over batch results
using(var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
{
    var currentResultSet = 0;
    while(reader.NextResult())
    {
        currentResultSet++;
        switch(currentResultSet)
        {
            case 1:
                while(reader.Read())
                {
                    // retrieve row data
                }
            case 2:
                // similar
            case 3:
                // similar
        }
    }
}
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.nextresult.aspx

But I don't think it's a nice way.

Answer (score 0):

Use the LoadWith method of the DataLoadOptions class to generate a single query in which you load all the relevant data if they can be Linq-ed through foreign key relations, read more [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.dataloadoptions.loadwith.aspx).

If there are no such relations, then you can implement a join query using your DataContext:
Read more here: [Simple Examples of joining 2 and 3 table using lambda expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5839896/simple-examples-of-joining-2-and-3-table-using-lamda-expression)